# Java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No execution available

Tags: java

I am trying to run a class in debug mode with following code

```
public void columnsList(List<TableRecord> records){

         Collections.sort(records, new StampDateComparator());
        for(TableRecord record : records){
            Table table = record.getTable();
            Field[] fields = table.fields();
            for(Field field : fields){
                field.getName();
                record.getValue(field);

            }
        }

    }

    public  static void main(String a[]){
        AuditLogComponent comp = new AuditLogComponent();
        List<TableRecord> records = new ArrayList<TableRecord>();
        records.add(new LogFolderRecord());
        records.add(new LogPeopleRecord());

        comp.columnsList(records);
    }
```

I am getting exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No execution available What i wrong am doing here?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No execution available

Comment: Something inside the classes you use throws this exception. Inspect the **full** stacktrace, it will tell you the exact class and line number, where the error occurs.

Comment: Yes i am wrong AuditLogComponent extends HtmlMacroComponent  this is the issue